# Ссылки меню отображаются не правильно

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Ссылка на сайт http://netahaki.tk/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылки меню отображаются не правильно, ховер эффект сместился из-за размера ссылок

Comment: А как должны отображаться? Задумка какая? Дайте больше информации, насколько я помню, у человечества телепатия еще не развита.

Comment: ховер эффект сместился из-за размера ссылок

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Comment: Покажите рисунком задумку, потому что не ясно в чем различие между имеющимся и задуманным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это особенность необычного шрифта, он выходит за свои границы.

Попробуйте задать значения `top` для всех линий в `%` и убрать `line-height: 30px;` для ссылок или сделать его побольше

Например:

Ссылкам задайте `line-height: 40px`, а линиям задайте сдвиг по вертикали ( свойство `top`)  `0%, 12%, 24%` и т.д. для всех линий